# componentWillRecieveProps method is not working properly: ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The following child component receives props from its parent. It then sets the props to it's own state using `getInitialState` and renders the value to the corresponding input fields using `this.state`.

I'm using `componentWillRecieveProps`to update the state of the child component when it receives new props.

Initially when the component is called it works correctly. The issue occurs when it's passed props for a second time, the corresponding button that triggers the props to be passed requires two clicks to set the child's state.

I am potentially using `componentWillRecieveProps` incorrectly?

```
getInitialState: function() {
  return {
    pitch: this.props.booking.pitch,
    email: this.props.booking.email,
    firstName: this.props.booking.firstName,
    arrivalDate: this.props.booking.arrivalDate,
  }
}, 

componentWillReceiveProps: function (props) {
  this.setState({
    pitch: this.props.booking.pitch,
    email: this.props.booking.email,
    firstName: this.props.booking.firstName,
    arrivalDate: this.props.booking.arrivalDate,
  })
},
```

Full Code:

```js
var React = require('react');
 var createReactClass = require('create-react-class');
 
 var ViewBooking = createReactClass({
   getInitialState: function() {
  return {
    pitch: this.props.booking.pitch,
    email: this.props.booking.email,
    firstName: this.props.booking.firstName,
    arrivalDate: this.props.booking.arrivalDate,
  }
   }, 
 
   componentWillReceiveProps: function (props) {
  this.setState({
    pitch: this.props.booking.pitch,
    email: this.props.booking.email,
    firstName: this.props.booking.firstName,
    arrivalDate: this.props.booking.arrivalDate,
  })
   },
  
   _handleInputChange: function(event) {
  const target = event.target;
  const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
  const name = target.name;
  var partialState = {};
  partialState[name] = value;
  console.log(partialState);
  this.setState(partialState);
   },
 
   _handleUpdateClose: function(e) {
  this.props.updateClose();
  e.preventDefault();
   },
 
   _handleUpdateBooking: function (e) {
  var tempBooking = {
    pitch: this.state.pitch,
    email: this.state.email,
    firstName: this.state.firstName,
    arrivalDate: this.state.arrivalDate,
  }
  this.props.updateBooking(tempBooking);
  e.preventDefault();
   },
 
   _handleDelete: function (e) {
  this.props.deleteBooking();
  e.preventDefault();
   },
 
   render: function() { 
  if (this.props.viewFormVisibility) {
    formVisibility = {"display": "block"};  
   } else {
    formVisibility = {"display": "none"};
   }
 
  return (
   <div>
   <form style={formVisibility}>
    <h4>View Booking</h4>
    <div className="form-group row">
      <label className="col-2 col-form-label">Pitch</label>
      <div className="col-10">
     <input value={this.state.pitch} onChange={this._handleInputChange} className="form-control" name="pitch" ref="inputPitch" type="number" id="example-number-input"/>
      </div>
    </div>
     <div className="form-group row">
    <label  className="col-2 col-form-label">First Name</label>
    <div className="col-10">
      <input value={this.state.firstName} onChange={this._handleInputChange} className="form-control" ref="firstName" name="firstName" type="text" id="example-text-input"/>
    </div>
     </div>
     <div className="form-group row">
    <label className="col-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
    <div className="col-10">
      <input value={this.state.email} onChange={this._handleInputChange} className="form-control" ref="inputEmail" type="email"  name="email" id="example-email-input"/>
    </div>
     </div>
     
     <div className="form-group row">
    <label className="col-2 col-form-label">Date</label>
    <div className="col-10">
      <input value={this.state.arrivalDate} onChange={this._handleInputChange} className="form-control" ref="arrivalDate" name="arrivalDate" type="date" id="example-date-input"/>
    </div>
     </div>
     <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this._handleUpdateBooking}>Save changes</button>
     <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this._handleUpdateClose}>Close</button>
     <button onClick={this._handleDelete} className="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
   </form>
    </div>
  )
   }
 })
  
 module.exports = ViewBooking;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I am potentially using componentWillRecieveProps incorrectly?

Yes, because you need to use `props.keyname` (props the parameter passed 
to this method), instead of `this.props` in `componentWillReceiveProps`.

Reason is, inside this `lifecycle` method `this.props` will have the previous `props` values not the new one, after this `lifecycle` method `this.props` will have the new `props` values.

As per [DOC](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops):

> componentWillReceiveProps() is invoked before a mounted component
>   receives new props. If you need to update the state in response to
>   prop changes (for example, to reset it), you may compare this.props
>   and nextProps and perform state transitions using this.setState() in
>   this method.

This is because `componentWillReceiveProps` will get called for each `setState` inside parent, so before setting the `newprops` inside child component first we should compare the prev value and new value, may be inside parent some other `state` value has been changed not the one we are passing to child component.

Do `console.log` on `this.props` and the `newProps` and check the result.

Use this:

```
componentWillReceiveProps: function (newProps) {
    this.setState({
        pitch: newProps.booking.pitch,
        email: newProps.booking.email,
        firstName: newProps.booking.firstName,
        arrivalDate: newProps.booking.arrivalDate,
    })
    console.log('previous value', this.props);    //print the previous values
    console.log('new values', newProps);          //new values
},
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you @Mayank, couldn't work that out from the documentation.

Comment: Now that you've quoted it out in your answer it seems pretty obvious. Accepted as correct answer.

Comment: glad, it helped you :) once i wasted sufficient amount of time for the same.