# Redux or setTimeout - how to watch props changes in child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, settimeout

I have App component, which loads JSON data from the server.
And after data is loaded, I update state of child component.

Now my function looks like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  setTimeout(()=> {
    if (this.state.users.length !== this.props.users.length) {
      this.setState({users: this.props.users});
      this.setState({tasks: this.getTasksArray()});
  }, 500);
}
```

I use setTimeout to wait if data is loaded and sent to child. But I'm sure, it is not the best way
May be, it's better to use redux instead of setTimeout.

Parent component loads data:

```
componentWillMount() {
  var _url = "/api/getusers/";
  fetch(_url)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then(users => {
    this.setState({ users });
    console.log("Loaded data:", users);
  });
}
```

Parent sends props with:

```
<AllTasks users={this.state.users} />
```

So, my question is: what is the best way to watch changes in child component?
I mean in this particular situation.

Comment: parent is making the api call and the response you are sending to child component correct?

Comment: yes. I updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is not the correct way because api calls will be asynchronous and we don't know how much time it will take.

So instead of using `setTimeout`, use `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle method in child component, it will get called whenever you change `props` values (state of parent component).

Like this:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps){
    this.setState({
        users: newProps.users,
        tasks: this.getTasksArray()
    })
}
```

One more thing, don't call `setState` multiple times within a function because `setState` will trigger re-rendering so first do all the calculations then do `setState` in the last and update all the values in one call.

As per **[DOC](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops)**:

> componentWillReceiveProps() is invoked before a mounted component
>   receives new props. If you need to update the state in response to
>   prop changes (for example, to reset it), you may compare this.props
>   and nextProps and perform state transitions using this.setState() in
>   this method.

**Update:**

You are calling a method from `cWRP` method and using the `props` values inside that method, `this.props` will have the updated values after this lifecycle method only. So you need to pass the newProps values as a parameter in this `function` and use that instead of `this.props`.

Like this:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps){
    this.setState({
        users: newProps.users,
        tasks: this.getTasksArray(newProps)
    })
}

getTasksArray(newProps){
    //here use newProps instead of this.props
}
```

Check this answer for more details: [componentWillRecieveProps method is not working properly: ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44725136/componentwillrecieveprops-method-is-not-working-properly-reactjs)

Comment: Thank you for advice about componentWillReceiveProps().
But it still works only if I use 

`componentWillReceiveProps(newProps){
  setTimeout(()=> {
    this.setState({
      users: newProps.users,
      tasks: this.getTasksArray()
    })
  }, 0);
}`

instead of:

`componentWillReceiveProps(newProps){
  this.setState({
    users: newProps.users,
    tasks: this.getTasksArray()
  })
}`

Comment: @alexfrize that will also work, but what's the use of setTimeout ? you will get the data in this lifecycle method setting the state after some time or immediately is totally upto you.

Comment: I don't know. That's why I'm asking

Comment: `setTimeout` is not required here, because what we want is: whenever any change happen update the state of child component immediately. why it is working with time out is you are setting the state after `x` milliseconds.

Comment: btw, if I console.log (newProps) before this.setState it shows me correct values

Comment: newProps (just the argument name you are replace that by abc or xyz) is nothing but the values that you are passing from parent component in props, if you do `console.log(newProps)` it will print the new values :) newProps is same as `this.props`.

Comment: just for information: I found the solution and added an explaination, why it works only with setTimeout.
But I'm not still quite sure that setTimeout is the best solution in my situation. So, if you have any other recomendations, please share.
Thanks again!

Comment: @alexfrize reason why it is working with `setTimeout`: see in `componentWillReceiveProps` method `this.props` will have the prev value not the updated one, after this method only `this.props` will have the new values, so when you are using timeout `this.props` will get updated within that time. Solution of this is , use the code in the same way i suggested and pass the `newProps` as parameter in `getTaskArray` method and use that instead of `this.props`.

Comment: @alexfrize check this answer for more details about why `this.props` is having the previous values in `componentWillReceiveProps` method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44725136/react-form-input-prop-update

Comment: got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

I have getTasksArray() function that depends of props and uses this.props.users.
So, when I update state like this:

```
this.setState({
  users: newProps.users, 
  tasks: this.getTasksArray()
})
```

getTasksArray() function uses empty array.
but when I split it to 2 lines and add setTimeout(fn, 0) like this:

```
this.setState({users: newProps.users}); 
setTimeout(()=> { this.setState({ tasks: this.getTasksArray() }, 0)
```

getTasksArray() function uses array that is already updated.
setTimeout(fn, 0) makes getTasksArray() to run after all other (even if I set timeout to 0 ms).

Here is the screenshot of console.log's without setTimeout:
[image]
And here is the screenshot with setTimeout:
[image]