# using componentWillReceiveProps with redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm confused now with redux, does `componentWillReceiveProps` still relevant? but I `console.log(this.props)` in `componentWillReceiveProps` I got empty object but do `console(this.props)` in render method, the result isn't the same.

Says I have a form, its value came from the async data, where I do the setState? if I do  the form is not controlled component.

Comment: Check [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44725136/componentwillrecieveprops-method-is-not-working-properly-reactjs/44725247#44725247), `this.props` inside `componentWillReceiveProps` will have the old props values not new, new props values will be available in first argument of this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`componentWillReceiveProps` passes the next props so, log these out rather `this.props`. It looks like this:
`componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, nextContext)`

More importantly, if you are not binding `react` to `redux`at the moment then changes to the `redux` store won't be available within your component. You should look at [react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux). This provides a `connect` function which takes a `mapStateToProps` function. `mapStateToProps` maps store state to the props of your component (container).

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps: any) {
        console.log('props current', this.props);
        console.log('props about to be', nextProps);
    }
    render() {
    // stuff here
    }
}
    const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
        const { counter } = state;
        // if the props of MyComponent has a counter property
        return {
            counter
        }
    };

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(MyComponent);
```

Once you have connected your component to the store then `this.props` will contain `counter` property.

Comment: very nice explanation