# Passing props in React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm afraid this is not going to be a well articulated question as I am somewhat new to React.

I'm modifying the methods of a component SeqAlignmentChart, I'm making the following calls from within componentWillReceiveProps

If I do "console.log(this)" I get

[image]

This all looks great.  However if I do "console.log(this.props)" I get

[image]

Note the 'data' field has gone from length 11 in "this" to length 1 in "this.props" while the 'width' property seems to have transferred. Apologies again for the formatting.

It seems very strange to me that when I print "this.props" I get a data object that doesn't contain the values I would be expecting.  Can anyone explain why 'console.log(this.props)' doesn't seem to be printing the same props as when I just do 'console.log(this)' ?

Thanks so much for any insight

edit: here is the code for the component, not sure which parts are relevant for this

```
export default class SeqAlignmentChart extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("in mount component $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$");
    console.log(this);
    this.seqAlignmentChart = new SeqAlignmentVis(
      ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this),
      this.props.data,
      {
        width: this.props.width ? this.props.width - 15 : 1000 - 15,
        margin: { top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10 }
      }
    );
    this.seqAlignmentChart.render();
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    console.log(this);
    console.log(this.props);
    console.log(this.props.data[0]);
    console.log(this.props.data.length);
    if (this.props.data.length > 1) {
      console.log("should rerender here ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^");
      this.componentDidMount();
    }
  }

  render() {}
}
```

Comment: Are you able to post component code please

Comment: sure, it's too long to fit here so I will edit the post

Comment: the other thing I'd look for is whether array being referenced by ```data``` prop is being mutated somewhere?

Comment: Did you call `super(props)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [documentation for componentWillReceiveProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops). Notice how it passes `nextProps` as an argument. `nextProps` refers to the props that the component is about to receive. `this.props` refers to the old props that the component currently has.

What happens when you `console.log(nextProps)`? Is this the data that you expected?

Comment: This does seem to be the answer, thanks! I suppose it was surprising for me that when I logged "this" I got the the new props.  I guess this is just weird because I'm in the middle of the update function?

Comment: That surprised me. I just made this [simple demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vv015wpvl0), and I logged the value of `this`. 

The `props` value seems to be as I expected. I'm wondering if there's something weird happening with your app.

Comment: See Mayank's answer, I think it explains what is happening
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44725136/componentwillrecieveprops-method-is-not-working-properly-reactjs

Answer (score 1):

Without a concrete example it is hard to debug, but I would guess 'this' is out of scope.

https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools

Could you try's React's Chrome Devtools? Pretty sure it can inspect React's state better than console.logging.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I've used the Devtools in the past but today it just says 'waiting for roots to load' so I gave up.
I don't think this is out of scope because when I console.log(this) it looks as expected